# VSTS - Show Feature Backlog item in Iteration View

Tags: azure-devops

I am using VSTS (visual studio team services) to manage the work progress of my project. Since I am the only person working on it and I just need a list to keep track of all to-dos, I decided to just create a Feature (the backlog item type) for all my work items.

My Question: Is there any way to show those features in the Iteration tab? I assigned the features to the corresponding iteration, but they don't show up in the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Feature` work item belongs to **portfolio backlogs** which provides a way to group related items into a hierarchical structure. The iteration tab shows the **requirement backlog** level work items. So you can not show a Feature work item on the Iteration tab.

You could use the default **requirement backlog** level work item (eg: Product Backlog Item) or customize a process template to add a custom work item type to **requirement backlog** to achieve your requirement:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you need one work item type, you can use user stories.

Also, you can create a new work item type 'MyFeature' for example - add that to Stories backlog,then you can just create 'MyFeautre' work items and assign it to the iteration. You will see in the 'Current Iteration' backlog and let us know if this helps.